# Memmove in Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, memmove

I'm trying to put this Memmove C code to assembly and don't get the supposed result.

I'm using x86-64 assembly on xubuntu and after debugging for 2 hours, I don't see where I'm wrong.

C memmove code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

extern void * memmove(void *dest, void *src, size_t n);

int main () { 
  char str1[] = "Geeks";  // Array of size 6
  char str2[] = "Quiz";   // Array of size 5 

  puts("str1 before memmove "); 
  puts(str1); 

  /* Copies contents of str2 to sr1 */
  memmove(str1, str2, sizeof(str2));

  puts("\nstr1 after memmove "); 
  puts(str1); 

  return 0; 
} 
/*

void * memmove(void *dest, void *src, size_t n) { 

    char *d = (char *) dest; 
    char *s = (char *) src; 

    if(s == d)
        return dest;

    if(s < d) { 
        //copy from back 
        s=s+n-1; 
        d=d+n-1; 
        while(n--) { 
            *d-- = *s--; 
        } 
    } 
    else { 
        //copy from front 
        while(n--) 
            *d++ = *s++; 
    } 
    return dest; 
} */
```

Assembly code:

```
.globl memmove

# RDI = dest
# RSI = src
# RDX = n

# R8 = d
# R9 = s

memmove:
    mov     %rdi, %r8       # d = dest
    mov     %rsi, %r9       # s = src
    jmp     if_equal

if_equal:
    cmp     %r8, %r9        # s == d
    jz      retDest
    ja      else            # s > d
    jb      if_s_minor      # s < d

if_s_minor:
    add     %rdx, %r9       # s = s + n
    sub     $1, %r9         # s = s - 1

    add     %rdx, %r8       # d = d + n
    sub     $1, %r8         # d = d - 1

    jmp     while1

while1:
    cmp     $0, %rdx        # n > 0 ?
    jna     retDest         # if n <= 0 go to retDest
    sub     $1, %rdx        # n--

    movb    (%rsi), %cl     # *dst-- = *src--
    movb    %cl, (%rdi) 

    leaq    -1(%r8), %r8    # *d--
    leaq    -1(%r9), %r9    # *s--
    jmp     while1

else:
    jmp     while2

while2:
    cmp     $0, %rdx        # n > 0 ?
    jna     retDest
    sub     $1, %rdx        # n--

    movb    (%rsi), %cl     # *dst = *src
    movb    %cl, (%rdi) 

    leaq    1(%r8), %r8 # *d++
    leaq    1(%r9), %r9 # *s++
    jmp     while2

retDest:
    mov     %rdi, %rax
    ret

.end
```

It was supposed to show "Quiz" on the second print but it shows this:

str1 before memmove 
Geeks

str1 after memmove 
Qeeks

Comment: *`char str1[] = "Geeks";  // Array of size 100`* - Nope. && I don't know what `memove()` is. Do you mean `memmove()`?

Comment: Yeah the array of size 100 is wrong. I misplaced the comment. And yes I meam memmove(), I changed it because i previously had a memmove function on the same file.

Comment: Edited now the post

Comment: Do you care about efficiency at all here?  Copying 1 byte at a time is very slow vs. using `movups` to copy 16 bytes at a time.  (x86-64 guarantees that SSE2 is available).  Or better AVX, or `rep movsb` if AVX isn't available.  Look at glibc's memcpy implementation for a good example.   https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S.html#19  (glibc memcpy just uses memmove.)

Comment: This is my "homework" for college and I'm supposed to move 8 bytes at all times if possible but as that's not always possible. And by the way, that link is full of stuff I can't use.

Comment: I'm not very worried with the efficiency. I just want it to work at first

Comment: @rkhb I only have the .c and .s files in the folder.

Comment: @rkhb: `memmove` behaviour is specified by ISO C and thus gcc is allowed to optimize accordingly.  If you want gcc to always use your custom implementation, use `gcc -fno-builtin-memmove`.  Or call your function something else.

Comment: @rkhb: `extern void * memmove(void *dest, void *src, size_t n);` is the correct prototype for ISO C `memmove`, other than missing a `const` qualifier on `src`.  It's not an "override".  gcc expects ISO C functions to be declared before use, except `__builtin_` funcs.  Normally that's in a header (like `string.h`), but after the preprocessor runs, the compiler doesn't know what came from where.  e.g. commenting it gives https://godbolt.org/z/jP9uj3 `warning: implicitly declaring library function 'memmove' with type 'void *(void *, const void *, unsigned long)' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> movb    (%rsi), %cl     # *dst = *src
> movb    %cl, (%rdi) 
> leaq    1(%r8), %r8 # *d++
> leaq    1(%r9), %r9 # *s++
> jmp     while2
> ```

The problem here is that your code changes the `%r8` and `%r9` registers, **but the `%rdi` and `%rsi` registers that are used in the actual move stay the same**, thus repeating copying the same byte again and again!

Same problem of course in the *while1* code.

Comment: sizeof(str2) returns 5